# CPUIn my laptop a double clock like diagram shows CPU usage and Random access memory [RAM] in percentage that is like 8% and 34%

Tags: macos

**In my laptop a double-clock-like diagram shows CPU usage and Random access memory [RAM] in percentage that is like 8% and 34%. I want know what does that percentage refer to?

Comment: more information needed maybe a screenshot. The tag says 'OS X' which version? What laptop? What application is saying this?

Comment: It is probably the current load on the CPU and RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it refers to the percentage of your RAM that's used to hold application data and running programs. Most of the rest is typically either page cache, kernel data, or free.